# Could not build wheels for pycryptodome

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

I'm trying to run a program that me and my friend build on another PC, I got the original files and when I'm trying to run the code it's asked me to install "Pyrebase", I'm trying to install and this is the error that I got:

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycryptodome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Python & PIP are up to date

Comment: setuptools updated also ?

Comment: Yes, I assume it is, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:

> pip install requests-toolbelt==0.10.1 &
> pip install pycryptodome~=3.12.0